# How to make a chord chart in Bokeh 0.13?

Tags: bokeh

Previous versions of Bokeh seem to have chord charts:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.12.4/docs/gallery/chord_chart.html

But not the latest version?

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/chord_chart.html [404s]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Chord` was part of `bokeh.charts` which was deprecated and removed many release ago. Most things that used to be in the old `bokeh.charts` are now simple to accomplish with the stable bokeh.plotting API, but `Chord` is one of the few exceptions. I would suggest looking at Holoviews, which is a very high level API that can output chord plots as Bokeh (and is officially endorsed by the Bokeh project):

http://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/Chord.html

With Holoviews, chord plots are typically a line or two:

```
%%opts Chord [label_index='name' color_index='index' edge_color_index='source'] 
%%opts Chord (cmap='Category20' edge_cmap='Category20')
hv.Chord((links, nodes)).select(value=(5, None))
```

Comment: Awesome. Although I can't help but feel like this information would also be useful in the Bokeh documentation somewhere.