# Group and label in Bokeh Chord chart 0.13

Tags: python, holoviews, chord-diagram

i'm trying to do a Chord chart using Holoview with Bokeh. I can do the first step, [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51718517/how-to-make-a-chord-chart-in-bokeh-0-13/51719039#51719039); yet, I cannot make the group nor show colors and label.
First, my data *chord = * :

```
 [['GK', 'WD ', 2],
 ['GK', 'C ', 1],
 ['GD', 'GK ', 1],
 ['GD', 'C ', 2],
 ['GD', 'WA ', 4],
 ['WD', 'GD ', 4],
 ['WD', 'C ', 1],
 ['WD', 'WA ', 2],
 ['WD', 'GA ', 1],
 ['C', 'GD ', 1],
 ['C', 'WD ', 1],
 ['C', 'WA ', 3],
 ['C', 'GA ', 2],
 ['C', 'GS ', 10],
 ['WA', 'C ', 2],
 ['WA', 'GA ', 9],
 ['WA', 'GS ', 7],
 ['GA', 'C ', 3],
 ['GA', 'WA ', 4],
 ['GA', 'GS ', 5],
 ['GS', 'C ', 6],
 ['GS', 'WA ', 1]]
```

The values are [source, target, value]. 
What got me stuck is the fact that the Chord chart does not automatically group the source, which happens if I use the Sankey chart instead.
So, I create my group and label:

```
group = [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7]
label = ['GK','GK','GD','GD','GD','WD','WD','WD','WD','C','C','C','C','C','WA','WA','WA','GA','GA','GA','GS','GS']
index =list(np.arange(0,22)
```

Nevertheless, the result is far from expected:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv

hv.extension('bokeh')
%output size=200
chords = pd.DataFrame(chord, columns=['source','target','value'])
%opts Chord [label_index='source' color_index='target' edge_color_index='source'] 
%opts Chord (cmap='Category20' edge_cmap='Category20')
hv.Chord(chords)
```

[image]

and if I pass

```
hv.Chord(chords, nodes)
```

I got this error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ndims'
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to pass `nodes` to `hv.Chord()` then bear in mind you should first call `hv.Dataset()` for `nodes` e.g.:
`nodes = hv.Dataset(nodes_df, 'index')`, where `nodes_df` is a pandas' dataframe.

and next:
`chord = hv.Chord((links, nodes)).select(value=(5, None)`