# Module bokeh: charts package is missing

Tags: python, charts, data-visualization, chord-diagram, missing-features

I am trying to draw visuals like Chord diagram which have relation links. I found few samples which are using module bokeh and charts and Chord for such kind of visualization.
But once I am trying use it

```
from bokeh.charts import output_file, Chord
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.sampledata.les_mis import data
```

getting error
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bokeh.charts'

**While my bokeh version is 2.3.3**

Anyone have any idea why getting error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a chord chart in Bokeh 0.13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51718517/how-to-make-a-chord-chart-in-bokeh-0-13)

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you are looking for isn't included in Bokeh anymore. To draw a Chord diagram you can use `HoloViews` instead, which can use `Bokeh` as a backend.

The example below comes from the [HoloView documentation](https://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/Chord.html).

```
import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts, dim
from bokeh.sampledata.les_mis import data

hv.extension('bokeh')
hv.output(size=200)

links = pd.DataFrame(data['links'])
hv.Chord(links)
```

This is the easiest way to draw a Chord diagramm. More complex options are also available.